# What's the main difference between react-native and react-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-dom

I was checking out the [React Native website](https://reactnative.dev/) then I realized you can build web apps with React Native as well as Android/iOS apps. I was wondering what's the main difference between **react-dom** and **React Native** if both of these libraries can build web apps and manipulate the DOM.
What are the main features **react-dom** has which **React Native** doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't actually build web apps with React Native. You can use `react-native-web` for that, which implements React Native APIs on top of `react-dom` and browser APIs, but is not the same thing as React Native and doesn't use React Native.